# How to post multipart request in Android and handle this request with Spring restful controller

Tags: android, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Here' my code. I want post a json object and a binary data

Android part:

```
final HttpURLConnection conn = URL.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
final String BOUNDARY = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
output.writeBytes("--" + BOUNDARY + "\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("\\r\\n");
                        output.write(sJsonMapper.writeValueAsString(para).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
output.writeBytes("\\r\\n");

output.writeBytes("--" + BOUNDARY + "\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png" + "\\r\\n");
output.writeBytes("\\r\\n");
output.write(new byte[]{0});
output.writeBytes("\\r\\n");

output.writeBytes("--" + BOUNDARY + "--" + "\\r\\n");
output.close();
```

Spring part:

```
@PostMapping("new")
public Ret newText(@RequestPart(name = "text") Text text,  @RequestPart(name = "data", required = false) MultipartFile data, @CurrentUser User user) {
}
```

But I always get an error that `MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'text' is not present`. How should I fix this?